# Video Background component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why would I need to use a video background component in my VueJS application instead of just putting a video element in my App.vue file?

```
<video autoplay muted loop id="bkgrdVideo">
    <source src="assets/headerVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

What is the benefit?

Comment: Who said you *need* to? You might *want* to, if you want your Vue app to be able to pause/play/stop/change it or something, but you don't *have* to make everything a component if you don't see a compelling reason to.

Answer (score 0):

When you create BackgroundVideo component.

- That code can be reused
- Styling can be scoped to that component
- That component can be tested in isolation
- It makes the parent cleaner

But you don't *need* to use a component for the background video.

Start without subcomponents, and as the project evolves, move parts of the code into components.
After a while you'll get a feel for what you like to write inline or as a component.